# What's the difference between MKAnnotation and MKPointAnnotation. Why would I use one over the other?

Tags: ios, mapkit

In the documentation they look exactly the same, they can both take Coordinate, Title, and Subtitle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MKAnnotation` is a protocol. Typically, you will create a NSObject subclass that implements this protocol. Instances of this custom class will then serve as your map annotation.

`MKPointAnnotation` is a class that implements MKAnnotation. You can use it directly if you want your own business logic on the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

@Sanjit has provided a good answer. But I want to add something. **MKAnnotaion** is a **protocol**. As I have attached screenshot below.

[image]

**MKPointAnnotation** is a **class**. It is Inherited from **MKShape** **class** and **MKShape** class **implements** **MKAnnotaion** **protocol**. Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

[image]